# In Powershell, how do I retrieve all the windows feature names associated with IIS 7.0 Installation?

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7

I am new to powershell but basically I want to be able to install IIS component by componenet in a powershell script. I should be able to look at these names and just plug it into Add-WindowsFeatures command. Look forward to your answers. I am doing this on Windows Server 2008 R2. Thanks!

Comment: Add-WindowsFeature was introduced in Server 2008 R2. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662309.aspx

Comment: edited. I apologize I meant W Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backwards compatible way (at least back to Win7) is to list all the features available and see the installation status with `dism /online /Get-Features` (or `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online | ft` on Win 10). Once you find the feature (case is important) you want, just let `ocsetup` (or `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` on Win10) do the work for you

```
# install windows features function
function InstallFeature($name){
    $winversion = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version;
    # Write-Host "detected $winversion"
    if ($winversion -like "10.*"){
        Write-Host "adding Windows 10 feature $name";
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName $name
    } else {
        Write-Host "adding Windows 7 feature $name";
        cmd /c "ocsetup $name /passive"
    }
}

InstallFeature IIS-WebServerRole

    InstallFeature IIS-WebServer

        InstallFeature IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
            InstallFeature IIS-DefaultDocument
            InstallFeature IIS-DirectoryBrowsing
            InstallFeature IIS-HttpErrors
            InstallFeature IIS-HttpRedirect
            InstallFeature IIS-StaticContent

        InstallFeature IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
            InstallFeature IIS-CustomLogging
            InstallFeature IIS-HttpLogging
            InstallFeature IIS-HttpTracing
            InstallFeature IIS-LoggingLibraries

        InstallFeature IIS-Security
            InstallFeature IIS-RequestFiltering
            InstallFeature IIS-WindowsAuthentication
            InstallFeature IIS-IPSecurity

        InstallFeature IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
            InstallFeature IIS-NetFxExtensibility
            InstallFeature IIS-ISAPIExtensions
            InstallFeature IIS-ISAPIFilter
            InstallFeature IIS-ASPNET
            InstallFeature IIS-CGI

        InstallFeature IIS-Performance
            InstallFeature IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
            InstallFeature IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic

        InstallFeature IIS-WebServerManagementTools 
            InstallFeature IIS-ManagementConsole 
            InstallFeature IIS-ManagementScriptingTools
            InstallFeature IIS-Metabase
```